# How should I treat image licenses in my program?

Tags: licensing, image, creative-commons, attribution, credits

In the program I'm making I have a pixtureBox (.NET) that is used to show related images. I found images after searching online, and some are CC BY-SA 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, and some belong to the public domain.

I read the related FAQ of Creative Commons, but its kind of vague as in it does not give me a clear enough image of what should I do if I intend to use the pictures in an application.

What I've done 'till now is to have a ToolTip pop-up message showing when the user gets the mouse pointer over the pictureBox, showing the name of the photographer, and the name of the license, of the current image.
Is that adequate enough ?

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but AFAIK for CC-BY-SA, you also need to either distribute the license text, or provide a link to a site where the license text can be found. Moreover, it might be a good idea to make the original image file easily accessible for anyone else (for example, by adding a link to the source). In case you modified the image, IMHO you need to make the modified file available to others under the same license as the original.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I made it so when the player hovers the mouse over it, the tooltip to show a message telling the user to click for image specific information. When the user clicks, a new form opens up, with the name of the photographer, the name of the license, and the whole text of the license in a textbox. I did no modification except from the usual resizing.

Comment: Have you read the license itself? In theory, the text of any license tells you exactly what you need to do when you distribute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pop-up is probably suitable for an image embedded in an application:

> CC licenses have a flexible attribution requirement, so there is not
>   necessarily one correct way to provide attribution. The proper method
>   for giving credit will depend on the medium and means you are using,
>   and may be implemented in any reasonable manner.

([source](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#how-do-i-properly-attribute-material-offered-under-a-creative-commons-license))

As for what you should put in the pop-up, [best practices](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution) suggest:

> "A good rule of thumb is to use the acronym TASL, which stands for
>   Title, Author, Source, License"

- Title of the work
- The name the Author
- Source of the work (e.g. a URL)
- Link to the licence

The title of the work can also be a link to the source.  A minimal example might look like this:

[Sunflowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflowers_(Van_Gogh_series)) by van Gough / [CC BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/)

If the source of the material included any extra notices or disclaimers then you may need to include those as well. And if you modify the images then you need to note that too.